# Como alterar CheckBox com onChange de DropDownList em Tabela ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, razor, checkbox, table, dropdown

Estou desenvolvendo uma site com ASP.NET MVC e Razor, tenho em uma de minhas páginas uma tabela com algumas colunas.

Tenho nessa tabela uma coluna State cujo tem um CheckBox e uma outra coluna contendo um DropDownList com algumas opções.

Gostaria que ao alterar o valor do DropDownList, o valor do CheckBox também fosse alterado para checado, pois eu utilizo as linhas checadas para enviar para o controller.

Já tentei utilizando o parents (JQuery) no elemento, mas obtenho uma resposta de que o parents não dá suporte.

Alguém poderia ajudar?

**VIEW**

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-reflow">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center bs-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th class="text-center col-md-5">Emitente</th>
            <th class="text-center">Manifestação</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.listaManifestacao)
        {
            <tr id="@item.Id">
                <td class="text-center">
                    <div class="bs-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
                </td>                    
                <td class="text-center">@item.Emitente</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => item.CodigoEvento, new SelectList(Model.listaOpcoesManifestacao, "Id", "Descricao", item.CodigoEvento), new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "CheckState(this);" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sem usar JQUery, apenas com Javascript Puro.

```js
function check() {
    document.getElementById("red").checked = true;
}

function muda(){
  
   for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByName("letras").length;i++)
      document.getElementsByName("letras")[i].checked = false;
  
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    
        document.getElementById(x).checked = true;
  
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="muda()">
  <option value="a">A
  <option value="b">B
  <option value="c">C
  <option value="d">D
</select>
<br><br>


<input type="radio" name="letras" id="a">A<br>
  <input type="radio" name="letras" id="b">B<br>
  <input type="radio" name="letras" id="c">C<br>
  <input type="radio" name="letras" id="d">D
```

Comment: o meu problema é a tabela onde os campos se encontram. Eu preciso pegar o valor do dropdownlist da linha que foi alterado e alterar o valor do checkbox na mesma linha da tabela e eu não estou conseguindo fazer isso.
Seu código funciona certinho, mas o meu problema também envolve a navegação pela tabela.

Comment: Podes colcoar o código sff?

Comment: Podes colocar o código sff?

Comment: Código da view postado, dei uma simplificada, pois minha tabela tem várias colunas, então retirei algumas para não ficar muito código

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho que essa coluna da sua tabela é redundante. Sua pergunta não ficou muito clara, mas li em um dos seus comentários que você não consegue atualizar a coluna do checkbox no banco de dados. Isso acontece porque esse seu checkbox sequer chega no controller, já que no seu código ele não possui um name.

E quando colocar o name, ele precisa estar de acordo com algumas regras para que o model binder consiga fazer seu trabalho. Para um melhor entendimento de como funciona o ModelBinding de coleções no AspNet Mvc 5, veja a solução para [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134725/como-enviar-checkbox-ao-controller/134754). Provavelmente é o que você precisa. 
Para uma explicação completa veja [este artigo](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

E para marcar o checkbox, com jquery (não testei o código)

```
function checkState(element) {
    var checkbox = $(element).closest('input[type="checkbox"]');
    if ($(element).val() === ''){
        checkbox.prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        checkbox.prop('checked', true);
    }
}
```