# Como Enviar checkbox ao Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

Possuo uma View em que numa lista de clientes existe na primeira coluna (table) um *CheckBox* para que possa ser possível selecionar um ou mais *clientes* e enviar ao *Controller*.

Na View estou utilizando o *CheckBox* puro e na model este mesmo campo é possui a propriedade `public bool Selecao {get; set;}` .

A minha duvida é qual a forma correta de enviar os *chekbox´s* selecionados para o *Controller*, para que eu possa efetuar as operações desejadas?

> Obs.: Cada *CheckBox* já esta recebendo o ID do cliente em sua
>   propriedade value.

Comment: A dúvida que ficou é `chekbox´s`, são vários ? O seu model é como, coloque seu código completo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu costumo fazer algo assim:

```
public class ClienteViewModel
{
    public ICollection<ClienteASelecionar> Clientes { get;set; }
}

public class ClienteASelecionar
{
    public bool Selecionado { get;set; }
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string NomeDoCliente { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
for(i=0; i < Clientes.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.Label(Model.NomeDoCliente)
    @Html.CheckBox("Clientes["+ i + "].Selecionado")
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ClienteId, new { @Name = "Clientes[" + i + "].ClienteId " }
}
```

Controler:

```
public ActionResult MeuMetodo(ClienteViewModel model)
{
    var selecionados = model.Clientes.Where(m => m.Selecionado).Select(m => m.ClienteId);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Eduardo pela dica!!!

Answer (score 2):

**Exemplo:**

***Model:***

```
public class Exemplo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

***Controller e View:***

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IList<Exemplo> exemplos = new List<Exemplo>();
    exemplos.Add(new Exemplo {Id = 1, Nome = "Nome 1"});
    exemplos.Add(new Exemplo { Id = 2, Nome = "Nome 2" });
    return View(exemplos);
}
```

---

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }
@using (Html.BeginForm("Resgatar", "Exemplo", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Display("Selecionar")
            </td>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Ids" value="@item.Id" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Alterar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

***Controller com ActionResult dos Id selecionados:***

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Resgatar(IEnumerable<int> Ids)
{
    return View();
}
```

Dessa forma receberá uma lista de Id de todos aqueles selecionados. Refaça a pesquisa na sua base e altere os dados necessários.

Comment: `Exemplo` não devia ter o `Id` do Cliente? Não deveria ser uma `List<Exemplo>`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu fiz uma baita confusão, já solucionei fazendo outra resposta